# Product of class sums in Group algebra

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $C_1, C_2, ... , C_s$ be conjugacy classes of a finite group G. Let $K_1, K_2, ... , K_s$  be the corresponding class sums. Choose representatives $g_{i} \in C_{i}$ and let $a_{ijv}$ be integers defined as follows

$K_{i}K_{j}$=$\sum_{v} a_{ijv}K_{v}$. Show that

$a_{ijv}=\frac{|C_{i}||C_{j}|}{|G|} \sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \frac{ \chi(g_{i}) \chi(g_{j}) \bar{\chi(g_{v})}}{\chi(1)}$.

I can't find a way to do it.  I can see why the coefficients do not depend on the elements in a conjugacy class. I think another way to interpret this problem is to think that these class sums are nothing but characterestic functions on conjugacy  classes and actually forms a basis of the space Z(L(G)) , that is the space of all class functions, and this problem actually asks to take convolution product two at a time of these characterestic functions and write in the linear combination of the basis and find the coefficients.I don't know whether the interpretation is right but I would like some help in approaching this problem.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct interpretation of the question: the $K_i$ is a basis of the centre of the group algebra, and the $a_{ijv}$ would be called the "structure constants" for multiplication, with respect to this basis.

We need to show that the $a_{ijv}$ may be found with the following formula:
$$ |G| a_{ijv} = |C_i| |C_j| \sum_V \frac{1}{\dim V} \chi_V (g_i) \chi_V (g_j) \overline{\chi_V (g_v)}$$
where the sum is over all irreducible representations $V$ of $G$, and $\chi_V$ denotes the (irreducible) character associated to the irreducible representation $V$.

Firstly, by column-orthogonality of characters, we have that $$\sum_V \chi_V(g_i) \overline{\chi_V(g_j)} = \delta_{ij} \frac{|G|}{|C_j|}.$$ So, fix a conjugacy class $C_v$ and apply $f_v(x) = \sum_V \chi_V(x) \overline{\chi_V(g_v)}$ to both sides of $K_i K_j = \sum_w a_{ijw} K_w$ to get
$$ \sum_V \chi_V(K_i K_j) \overline{\chi_V(g_v)} = a_{ijv} |G| $$

From here we just have to show that the left hand side is what we want, which we can do by considering each term of the sum individually. Fix an irreducible representation $V$. Since $K_i$ and $K_j$ are elements of the centre of the group algebra, they will each act on $V$ by a scalar, so we may write $\chi_V(K_i) = \lambda_i (\dim V)$, $\chi_V(K_j) = \lambda_j (\dim V)$ for some $\lambda_i, \lambda_j \in \mathbb{C}$. Crucially, we also have that $$\chi_V(K_i K_j) = \lambda_i \lambda_j (\dim V) = \frac{1}{\dim V} \chi_V(K_i) \chi_V(K_j).$$

So now we have
$$\sum_V \frac{1}{\dim V}\chi_V(K_i) \chi_V(K_j) \overline{\chi_V(g_v)} = a_{ijv} |G|$$

Finally, since characters are constant on conjugacy classes, we have $\chi_V(K_i) = |C_i| \chi_V(g_i)$ and similarly for $\chi_V(K_j)$, and so we are done.

Comment: can you tell me what $\chi(K_{i}K_{j})$  means because these $K_{i}$ are not elements of groups. But characters are applied on elements of groups.

Comment: Since characters are linear (being traces), you can use the linearity to extend them to the whole group algebra. For example, $\chi_V(2g + h) = 2 \chi_V(g) + \chi_V(h)$. This is consistent with how $2g + h$ would act on $V$ as a linear operator.

Comment: Ok I got it....